# Web development plugins required but for specific Eclipse installation

Tags: java, html, plugins, myeclipse, eclipse-3.4

I have to use Eclipse Ganymede `3.4.2`. Please don't ask me to upgrade to another version. It is out of my hands.

What should I install in order to use the visual editors for `html`,`xml` files and in general for web development?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know may be you are looking for [MyEclipse 7.0](http://www.myeclipseide.com/Article85.html) with its genuine [MyEclipse Visual Web Designer](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-12.html)
Also check for [MyEclipse HTML Designer Tutorial](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webdesigner/)

Comment: What is `MyEclipse`?Is it the same as `Ganymede`?

Comment: 7.0 is based on Eclipse 3.4 known as Ganymede.

Comment: I am interested to use plugins to enhance my current `Ganymede` installation.`MyEclipse` is to use another `IDE` right?

Comment: It's the same IDE but extended and enhanced providing custom plugins to support for java EE development. There's an installation module that install full stack of tools with java integrated or an update site archive to install onto Eclipse SDK.

Comment: You mean install this in my existing `Ganymede` installation?